# How to use cbt to delete range of rows with a prefix key from BigTable?

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable, cbt

Looks like I can read rows with a prefixed key using cbt like so:

```
cbt -project someproject -instance someinstance read sometable prefix=abc
```

But how can I use the `cbt` command to delete those rows as selected by the above command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be able to do this using only `cbt`, you would to parse the output of the read command and iterate through each result executing the `deleterow` command for the specific rows.

Alternatively, you could use one of the [Bigtable’s Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/libraries) which would be much faster.

Like in the Java client, you will find this same functionality in the other clients as well, like in the [DropRowRangeRequest class](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Bigtable.Admin.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Bigtable.Admin.V2.DropRowRangeRequest.html#Google_Cloud_Bigtable_Admin_V2_DropRowRangeRequest_RowKeyPrefix) for the C# Client Library.

**EDIT:** To delete a few rows using only `cbt` you could use something like this:

```
for x in `cbt -project my-project -instance my-instance read my-table prefix=abc | grep "abc"`; do 
  cbt -project my-project -instance my-instance deleterow my-table $x;
done
```

Comment: It would be awesome if someone can write a one-line terminal command that use the read output to delete rows... I have only less than a hundred rows to delete. So for now I don't really need it to be done very efficiently.

Comment: @FuyangLiu Here's an `xargs` variation I've been using `cbt -instance my-instance read my-table prefix=abc | grep '^abc' | xargs -I '{}' cbt -instance my-instance deleterow my-table {}`

Comment: You should get like 1000 upvotes. it worked perfectly.