# Delete specific rows in big table based on prefix

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have data similar to this in Bigtable

```
test_2410_demo_1996
  cf_abc:dummy_6834                  @ 2021/05/21-05:30:00.000000
    "2021-05-21T00:00:00.746Z"
----------------------------------------
test_2410_demo_2441
  cf_abc:dummy_6833                  @ 2021/05/22-23:06:05.000000
    "2021-05-22T17:36:05.560Z"
  cf_abc:dummy_6834                  @ 2021/05/21-05:30:00.000000
    "2021-05-21T00:00:00.746Z"
----------------------------------------
test_2410_demo_2553
  cf_abc:dummy_6833                  @ 2021/05/22-23:05:39.000000
    "2021-05-22T17:35:39.144Z"
  cf_abc:dummy_6833                  @ 2021/05/22-23:03:53.000000
    "2021-05-22T17:33:53.242Z"
  cf_abc:dummy_6833                  @ 2021/05/22-23:02:50.000000
    "2021-05-22T17:32:50.301Z"
  cf_abc:dummy_6834                  @ 2021/05/21-05:30:00.000000
    "2021-05-21T00:00:00.746Z"
----------------------------------------
```

I am trying to delete rows with dummy_6833 by using this command

```
cbt -instance="my-instance" read <my-table> prefix=test_2410 | grep dummy_6833 | xargs -I '{}' cbt -instance="my-instance" deleterow <my-table> {}
```

The command is executed but the records are not getting deleted. Please suggest how can I achieve the same. Please suggest if I can achieve this by some script or programmatically in java

Comment: Hi, did you get any error message ? can you share a screen shot or log after the execution?

Comment: Hi, regarding your question how to do it with java here is an example you could use: [Using the client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library)and you can also take a look on this post [How to use cbt to delete range of rows with a prefix key from BigTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570841/how-to-use-cbt-to-delete-range-of-rows-with-a-prefix-key-from-bigtable)

Answer (score 0):

```
cbt deleterow <table-id> <row-key> [app-profile=<app-profile-id>]
```

You can refer document for all delete BT
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference